pd.Timestamp() behavior in Pandas
Trying to understand why t1 takes current date whereas t2 takes the epoch date in Pandas in Python. Any thoughts would help.
import pandas as pd

t1 = pd.Timestamp("23:12:05")
print("t1:",t1)

t2 = pd.Timestamp(1)
print("t2:"t2)

Output:
t1: 2024-07-23 23:12:05
t2: 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000001

